# how to get the password from ask-vault-pass as fact to use it inside a playbook

Tags: ansible, passwords, ansible-vault

Is there a way to use the password given in ask-vault-pass inside a playbook.
example, assuming I give test123 as vault password and the ask-vault-pass is saved in a fact called "ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD":

ex:

```
$: ansible-playbook -l myhost myplaybook.yml -i myinventory --ask-vault-pass
Vault password: test123
```

myplaybook.yml:

```yaml
- host: all
  pre_tasks:
    - name: "print the vault password"
      debug:
        - msg: "{{ ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD }}"
```

output should be something like:

```
TASK [DEBUG] ***************************************
ok: [myhost] => {
     "msg": "test123"
}
```

the question is: is there a fact like ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD that store the password given with ask-vault-pass or any other way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I store the password in a file named `.vault-password` at the repository root. Although it's git-ignored, be aware that any admin can read it.

In `~/.zshrc` I have:

```bash
export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=.vault-password
```

Doing so allows you to run CLI without typing the password anymore, *and* to read the password into a variable using [file lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html).

```yaml
- name: Reading Vault password
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    ansible_vault_password: "{{ lookup('file', '.vault-password') }}"

- name: Printing Vault password
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: ansible_vault_password
```

Be also aware that it won't be redacted.